# listing records in given date range in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, date, datetime

I have a database that hold records with dates in form of **varChar**

my database:

```
------------------------
| id | name |    date  |
------------------------
| 1 | Mark  |01-11-2020|
------------------------
| 2 | Mark  |01-06-2020|
------------------------
| 3 | Mark  |01-07-2020|
------------------------
```

the date format is ***day-month-year***

i have 2 string variables:

```
var1: 01-05-2020
var2: 20-06-2020
```

when i enter there variables to my sql i dont get the right result which is

```
01-06-2020
```

my code is

```
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->where('date >=', '01-05-2020');
    $this->db->where('date <=', '20-06-2020');
    $query = $this->db->get('db');
    $data["records"] = $query->result();
```

Comment: date comparison stuff does not work so well when dates are store a text and not as Date or Datetime columns

Comment: Is it too late to change the database so you can store your dates properly in a DATE or DATETIME column?

Comment: unfortunately its too late to change to DATE

Comment: does this work `$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(date,%d-%m-%Y) >=', '2020-05-01');` and of course change the other `where` in a similiar way

Comment: it does not work :(

Comment: try this
`$where = "date >= '2020-05-01' and date <= '2020-06-20' ";
$this->db->where($where);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert string you are trying to search too

```
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') >=", "STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2020','%d-%m-%Y')");
    $this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') <=", "STR_TO_DATE('20-06-2020','%d-%m-%Y')");
    $query = $this->db->get('db');
    $data["records"] = $query->result();
```

you may find [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e44840/1) helpful